# Nodejs:Unable to Pass variable from app.js to Index.html

Tags: node.js, firebase, express

I am struggling from two days to do this operation but failure.In App.js i have tried:-

```
var express = require('express'),
  app = express(),
   httpServer = http.Server(app);
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/data'));
app.get('./index',
function (req, res) {
res.render('index', {});
    getUserInfo(req) //get your information to use it.
        .then(function (userinfo) {  //return your promise
            res.json({ "name": userinfo.Name});
            //you can declare/return more vars in this res.json.
            //res.cookie('name', name); //https trouble
        })
    .error(function (e) {console.log("Error handler " + e)})
    .catch(function (e) {console.log("Catch handler " + e)});
res.send('Hello World');
});
app.listen(8080);
```

My index.html code goes here

```
 $.ajax({
        url: '/index',
        headers: {
            Authorization: 'Bearer ' + idToken
        },
        processData: false,
    }).done(function (data) {
        localStorage.setItem('name', data.name);
        //or whatever you want done.
    }).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus) {
        var msg = 'Unable to fetch protected resource';
        msg += '<br>' + jqXHR.status + ' ' + jqXHR.responseText;
        if (jqXHR.status === 401) {
            msg += '<br>Your token may be expired'
        }
        displayError(msg);
    })
```

But unfortunately i get this error when i open index from local server:8080 :-

```
Cannot GET /
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `app.get('./index')` to `app.get('/index')`